# Excluding anonymous classes in tests

Tags: testing, gradle

After some modifications for test configuration

```
test {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include '**/*Test.class'
    include 'lt/inventi/apollo/scenarios/**'
}
```

My tests started to fail with error `java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public constructor`
so my workaround is like so

```
test {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include '**/*Test.class'
    include 'lt/inventi/apollo/scenarios/**'
    exclude '**/*$*' //fixed 
}
```

Is this correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you turn off test class scanning, it's your responsibility to filter out all non-test classes. If you can't be more specific than `scenarios/**`, you'll have to compensate with an exclude (like you already do).

Note that it's perfectly fine to use test class scanning together with include/exclude filters.

Comment: No I didn't. The procedure is as follows: 1. Find all classes in the test source set (e.g. all classes under `src/test/java`) 2. Filter using includes/excludes (if any) 3. Filter using test class scanning (if turned on) 4. Execute all remaining classes with JUnit/TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue exclusively on a mac, and found 2 issues:

- There was a bug [#4544](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4544) on Gradle versions prior to 4.7, causing inner classes to be picked up
- The mac JVM I happen to use (Zulu 1.8, installed via [SDKMan](https://sdkman.io/)) had issues when namespaces were capitalised (and the associated folders were too).  This was fine with Zulu 1.8 in ubuntu, but lower-casing the folders seemed to do the trick